# coturn in Docker Swarm does not connect (kurento)

Tags: docker, webrtc, docker-swarm, kurento, coturn

When I try to connect to my app I can connect and start sending and receiving ICE candidates. But the negotiation does not complete the rtc connection state eventually gets to "Checking", and then after about 30 seconds drops to "Failed"

I have this working with a local setup, but once I have deployed to AWS this starts to fail.
I went and bjorked the settings in AWS and opened all the ports and now I can reach the coturn service (returns 200 when requesting through http), and the Trickle service [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) works fine.

I am using the Kurento Media Server and hoping to make a websocket connection to that service. As I mentioned this works locally so I'm fairly sure that there is nothing wrong with how I'm making the request but instead it is a configuration option with AWS or my docker compose file.

I have a docker compose file with three apps in it:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  media-controller:
    image: my-custom-images/my-server:latest.version
    volumes:
      - "tmp-video-storage:/tmp"
    ports:
      - "8899:8899"
  kurento-media-service:
    image: kurento/kurento-media-server:6.6.0
    volumes:
      - "tmp-video-storage:/tmp"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
  coturn:
    image: my-custom-images/coturn:lastest.version
    ports:
      - "3478:3478/udp"
      - "3478:3478/tcp"
volumes:
  tmp-video-storage:
```

coturn's /etc/turnserver.conf

```
min-port=49152
max-port=65535
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
realm=my-domain.com
log-file stdout
user=username-placeholder:password-placeholder
external-ip=public-ip/private-ip
listening-port=3478
```

Output from Trickle Ice Candidates:

```
0.004   1   host    1019731727  udp 192.168.1.104   64702   126 | 32543 | 0
0.068   1   srflx   3180321211  udp 10.255.0.2  64702   100 | 32542 | 255
0.091   1   relay   610197926   udp 35.183.10.44    50008   2 | 32542 | 255
0.106   1   host    1917068287  tcp 192.168.1.104   9   90 | 32542 | 255
0.106   Done
0.120
```